# How to exclude a domain from redirection in Apache2

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, redirect, https

I have a blanket redirect setup on the server like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            #redirect all port 80 traffic to 443
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I would like to exclude one domain and I cant seem to work it out...

Here is what I tried:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            #redirect all port 80 traffic to 443
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !example.com
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
    </IfModule>
```

However it still redirects http://example.com to https://example.com. What am I doing wrong?

PS. I tried in other browser so browser caching should not be an issue.

Comment: What if you try this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !=example.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have mispelled the configuration here (Notice the closing brace)

Replace

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !example.com
```

with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.com
```